# Visual Studio Community Edition 2019 doesn't find any tests

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest, googlemock

I have created a C++ project called Googletest in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. In the project I have installed Gmock as a nugget(gmock 1.11.0). I have two cpp files(Googletest.cpp and Test.cpp).

Googletest.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (strcmp("test", argv[1]) == 0)
    {
        ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
        return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(FooTestSuite, Foo1) {
    ASSERT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

The executable works properly. It runs the test or just says "Hello". The problem is that VS doesn't find any test, so that I can't use the test explorer. Does anyone know how to fix the issue? I have uploaded the project on github: https://github.com/tellass567/vs-googletest

Comment: Just a longshot, but on some releases of VS you had to install C# to get the test explorer to work. Possibly some hidden dependencies on .NET.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed [Test Adapter for Google Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2022) and it can't discover Google tests, be sure the test names end with Test or Tests, otherwise Test Adapter is not able to discover unit tests

```
TEST(FooTests, Foo1) {
    ASSERT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

You may add alternative test name RegExes in **Tools > Options > Test Adapter for Google Test** to help Test Adapter to discover unit tests, see [Trait Regexes](https://github.com/microsoft/TestAdapterForGoogleTest#trait_regexes).